# $(\sqrt{n}\cos(nx))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

I want to prove that $(\sqrt{n}\cos(nx))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a divergent sequence for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. I would like to know if there are any mistakes or ways to improve my proof. Thank you.
(Note: I use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(nx_0)\neq 0$ as a given lemma).

My attempt:

Let $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$: I already know that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(nx_0)\neq 0$ so that means there exists $\bar{\varepsilon}>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ there is $n\geq N$ such that $|\cos(nx_0)-0|=|\cos(nx_0)|\geq\bar{\varepsilon}$ so the set $A:=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:|\cos(nx_0)|\geq\bar{\varepsilon}\}$ is infinite and we can build an increasing sequence $(n_j)_{j=0}^{\infty}$ by setting $n_j:=\min\{n\in A:n\neq n_i, i<j\}$ and we have $|\sqrt{n_j}\cos(n_jx_0)|\geq\sqrt{n_j}\bar{\varepsilon}>0$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$. Now if we let $M>0$ we know there will be some $J\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sqrt{n_J}>\frac{M}{\bar{\varepsilon}}$ so $\sqrt{n_J}\bar{\varepsilon}>M$ which implies $|\sqrt{n_J}\cos(n_Jx_0)|>M$ and this is true for all $j\geq J$ so $|\sqrt{n_j}\cos(n_jx_0)|\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}+\infty$ which in turn implies that $\sqrt{n_j}\cos(n_jx_0)$ cannot converge too (i.e. it either goes to $\pm\infty$ or it does not have a limit).

Comment: What you know is that the limit does not exist, not that it is non-zero. Once you know that, and multiplying it by $n^a$ for $a>0$ also does not have a limit.

Comment: @martycohen I see what you are saying but since I wanted an "$\varepsilon - \delta$" proof, for the mechanics of the proof I used that fact which I do know (see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964978/inequality-and-sequence-of-functions) and that's why I said "I use the fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\cos(nx_0)\neq 0$ as a given lemma". Do you have any comments on the correctness of my actual proof? Thank you for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already know that for every $x$, the sequence $\cos(nx)$ does not tend to $0$, then the proof is over. Indeed, the fact that $(\sqrt{n}\cos(nx))$ converges directly implies that $\cos(nx)$ must tend to $0$...

Comment: thank you for your interest in my question but does your comment mean that my proof is right or wrong? Because that is what I want to know.

Comment: This seems correct (strictly logically speaking), but in my opinion, it is far too complicated !